# C#/.net Program compares a registry directory for differences over time. Works for the console test app, but not for the service

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services, registry

I have a service I am trying to create in Visual Studio that checks the values of 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall' when the service starts and stores it as a hashset. Every 20 minutes, it pulls another hashset of the directory and compares the two sets to effectively see if a program is installed based on the addition of the uninstalled value in the registry. I used a separate project, also using Visual Studio that is a console app for ease of testing the logic before I created the service app.

The issue I am running into is that the code is logically the same from the service to the console app, however only the console app functions as anticipated. When I install a program, my test is TeamViewer, it sees the new entry in the registry and set, then sends an email/writes to console that a change was found. I believe the main difference is that the service was forced to be built with .net framework and the console app is just .net.

The main service directory is WatchTower.
The console testing directory is Consoletest.
The class file in question is InstalledApps.cs for both directories.

the code can be found here: https://github.com/TartCart/WatchTower.git

---

I have printed the output of the service to a logfile and see that it is able to access the registry, and populate the hash sets, but it seems like the service is unable to get an updates set from the registry after it accesses it for the first time.. whereas in the console app it gets the updated set. I've checked permissions and utilized chatGPT to its fullest extent for testing/debugging but something under the hood is just not giving as far as I can tell with my limited experience.

I am inexperienced with software development as I am sure my code will reveal - any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: So you probably have three variables: .NET Framework vs. .NET / Console vs. Service / different user contexts. Maybe try to change only one of these at a time instead of all three at once.

Comment: Did you check that "user account" the service is installed with, has permissions to read from the registry? I didn't fully read the code, but if it works as a test-console. That is all I can think of as an issue.

I believe access to registry requires admin access, and if you are just plain installing a windows service, it would normally defaullt to the "default local account". ie. Not an admin account.

And likely the console version is running with your AD user, which is likely an admin

Comment: The user account it is ran as is local system which I understand is greater than my administrator privs which I run the consoletest as, regardless the sets are able to retrieve the values from the registry so access does not appear to be the issue.

Comment: I can't tell what's the issue just by reading the code but I noticed not everything is try-catched in `installedApps.cs`, especially not the event handler. I suppose an exception might be raised somewhere and goes unnoticed. I also wonder: why .net framework? I'm sure windows service can be created with .net 8 too.

Comment: When I created it in Visual Studio, it only allowed .net framework from the project creation menu. I thought it had something to do with the project/service integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are checking both the 32-bit and 64-bit registry locations.

```
SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

You can do that by specifying the `RegistryView` on the base key:

```
const string KeyName = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
var allSubKeyNames = new List<string>();

foreach (var regView in new List<RegistryView> { RegistryView.Registry32, RegistryView.Registry64 })
{
    using (var baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, regView))
    {
        using (var subKey = baseKey.OpenSubKey(KeyName))
        {
            allSubKeyNames.AddRange(subKey.GetSubKeyNames());
        }
    }
}

using (var subKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(KeyName))
{
    allSubKeyNames.AddRange(subKey.GetSubKeyNames());
}

//do something with allSubKeyNames
```

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/32-bit-and-64-bit-application-data-in-the-registry)

Additionally, you should probably open and close the key inside `Timer_Elapsed` rather than opening it and holding it static.

Comment: Great comment, I'll check these out and report back, thanks

Comment: I have made the changes to close the keys when done utilizing them and reformatted to not hold static. I also implemented error checking with try catch. I don't receive any errors and still am facing the same issue. I am not sure what or where to check next.

Comment: I updated my answer to include some code that may be helpful with switching to the 32 and 64 bit registry keys. It also includes the subkeys under HKCU, which will be used if the program was installed for only the current user and not all users.